# How do I get Laravel echo to work properly with inertia.js and vue.js in a Laravel project?

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-echo, inertiajs

I am trying to implement notifications broadcast to a private channel in a Laravel project using Pusher and Laravel echo. The frontend uses Vue and Inertia. I need help with three issues:

1. I initiate a connection to Pusher with Laravel echo only after a user logs into the app, but I get a 419 status and the connection fails. This is the console output:

> Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-eu.pusher.com:443/app/XXX6d8b6015bf99XXX?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"xhr_streaming","url":"https://sockjs-eu.pusher.com:443/pusher/app/XXX6d8b6015bf99XXX?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3"}]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 131880.30956555"]
> vendor.js:40979 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/pusher/auth 419 (unknown status)
> ajax @ vendor.js:40979
> vendor.js:41360 Pusher :  : ["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 419 from /pusher/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users"]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on private-user.12 for pusher:subscription_error"]

But when I do a page refresh, the user gets authenticated on a new socket. This console output:

> Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-eu.pusher.com:443/app/XXX6d8b6015bf99XXX?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
> Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 131841.30968485"]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"XXX6d8b6015bf99XXX:a0e7a444XXXX4152c4bb0716XXXX1b83bd5a600592XXXX27c4844ca5b4f1","channel":"private-user.12"}}]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"private-user.12","data":{}}]
> vendor.js:41325 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on private-user.12 for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]

The session details on Laravel telescope show that the call that gave the 419 status and the one that succeeded both have identical token information.

I know the 419 status has to do with a missing/invalid CSRF token but I thought Laravel handles this out of the box, and as stated above, it doesn't appear to be the issue.

I now don't know what else to do to fix this so that when a user logs in and the dashboard component (Inertia page) is rendered, the echo instance is initiated and pusher subscribe call is made for authenticated user without requiring a full http page load.

This is my bootstrap file:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.EchoService = { 
    init: () => 
    new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        }
    }
})
};
```

And this is my vue file:

```
  mounted() {
       window.EchoService.init().private(`user.${this.$page.props.auth.user.id}`)
          
  },

  destroyed() {
       window.EchoService.init().leave(`user.${this.$page.props.auth.user.id}`);
  },
```

2. The second issue is that my destroy method doesn't appear to get called when the user logs out. The user connection remains active after logging out until I do a page refresh. I don't know how to get this to work when inertia again, navigates away upon logging out without a full http request (full page reload).
3. The third issue is that even after a successful connection, I do not get any callback/data. Nothing gets logged to the console or rendered to the page. But I can see the data on pusher debug console.

For the last two issues, my guess is that I'm probably not implementing my vue component the correct way.

Comment: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/168 this may be of some assistance

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a look.